# I cant find correct information about my laptop max ram capacity

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, motherboard

I have msi ge60-0nc-037tr laptop using windows 7 when i check the model of my motherboard

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
```

return MS-16GA model motherboard when i check max capacity of that motherboard from internet it say max 8gb ram supported. 
sources:
 https://www.memorystock.com/memory/MicrostarIntMS16GA.html
 https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/MSI-MS-16GA/503#Compatibility

But https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE60_0NC/Specification says my laptop support max 16 gb ram.

I scan my laptop with https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner 
it also say i have 16gb support.
So which way is correct to check max ram capacity of laptop ?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What do you mean "when i check the internet"? You posted two links that you said say the same thing.

Comment: İ mean when i check ms-16GA moterboard max capaticy of ram it say 8gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manufacturer](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE60_0NC/Specification) is always right.  [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner) is also a highly credible source of memory information. Never heard of MemoryStock, so since they disagree with both MSI and Crucial, I'd think they had the wrong info.

Comment: Yeah i feel like that but my model is really old even for msi Ge60 models and it special product for Turkey i belive.I see turkish [post](https://forum.donanimhaber.com/msi-ge60-0nc-037tr-incelemesi--62123514) for review of exactly same model of mine it also say max  capacity is 8gb.I dont want to waste my money for not working 16gb rams :d (sorry for bad english)

Comment: I would always believe the manufacturer before believing a third party.

Comment: yeah thx for answer guys.Cpu-z also show same chipset with msi spesification.It is black friday here i am going to buy the rams

Answer (score 0):

You usually have two Slots for RAM in today's laptops
If you open the cover, on the bottom of the laptop, 
where the RAM is, the slot is below the upper stick to
place more RAM in. Each should hold 8 GB each.

From your Post:

DDR3 1333/1600MHz, 2 slots, Max. 16GB